# Ошибка AttributeError: 'LabeledPrice' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Создаю небольшой магазин в телеграмме и при попытке добавить способы доставки, появляется ошибка: AttributeError: 'LabeledPrice' object has no attribute 'to_dict'. Вот пример кода.
`

```
shipping_options = [
    ShippingOption(id='Delivery1', title='Delivery_text1').add_price(LabeledPrice('Delivery1', 10000)),
    ShippingOption(id='Delivery2', title='Delivery_text2').add_price(LabeledPrice('Delivery2', 30000)),
    ShippingOption(id='Delivery3', title='Delivery_text3').add_price(LabeledPrice('Delivery3', 40000))
]

@bot.shipping_query_handler(func=lambda query: True)
def shipping(shipping_query):
    bot.answer_shipping_query(shipping_query.id,
        ok = True,
        shipping_options = shipping_options,
        error_message = 'Что то пошло не так.')
```

`
Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил это, переписав в модуле telebot исходном файле types.py в классе ShippingOption функцию to_json, вот как она выглядит после исправлений:

```
def to_json(self):
        price_list = []
        for p in self.prices:
            price_list.append({'label':str(p.label), 'amount':str(p.amount)})
        json_dict = json.dumps({'id': self.id, 'title': self.title, 'prices': price_list})
        return json_dict
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ